# Restricting random generated email on site to register

Tags: validation, email, cakephp

I want user not to register on site using random emails generated randomly. For example Mailinator.com 
How I can restrict those emails from my site when use register using those emails

Comment: There's no way to automate that.  You'd need to create a blacklist (or find an existing blacklist).

Comment: Its good idea but there are hundreds of quick email provider, and Email Validation has its own limit

Comment: Though its a good question, I will wait if someone comeup with right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one more way but i am not sure it will work or not. This is [Link](http://streetsie.com/wp-content/uploads/phpBB2-spam-email-banlist.txt) for PhpBB blacklisted email. you can add them in your database table named blacklists 
(according to cakephp modelname requirement) 
Then in singup function compare both email

```
  $mailchk = $this->request->data['User']['email'];
 $mailexists = $this->request->data['Blacklist']['email']
```

compare this both email and if they mathch kick that user out.
but this is ideal way, I am not sure it will work or not because Programming functions have their own limt

you can use preg_match or FILTER_VALLIDATE_EMAIL to compare both data

Comment: So there is no way to do that ?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do that

Comment: You are the man. I couldn't thought that way.

Comment: If you find it helpfull, make that arrow go green

Answer (score 1):

Notice that Mailinator has many different domain names. You should see where the `A` or `MX` records of the domain name part resolves to, to filter mailinator effectively. Notice that it will also cause me to not use your service:

```
% host mailinator.com 
mailinator.com has address 207.198.106.56
mailinator.com mail is handled by 10 mailinator.com.

% host suremail.info 
suremail.info has address 207.198.106.56
suremail.info mail is handled by 10 suremail.info.
```

So effectively you'd want your blacklist to block by all of these

```
- the domain part of the address
- the A record of the domain
- the A record of the highest priority MX record of the domain
```